# ZF2 Session Validators

Tags: session, zend-framework2

I implemented the HttpUserAgent and RemoteAddr validators in Zend Framework 2 to help prevent session hijacking.

```
use Zend\Session\Validator\HttpUserAgent;
use Zend\Session\SessionManager;

$manager = new SessionManager();
$manager->getValidatorChain()->attach('session.validate', array(new HttpUserAgent(), 'isValid'));
```

It does seem to stop hijacked sessions however, it doesn't let me display a nice error message or reroute the user to the login page, Instead I get this PHP Error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Session\Exception\RuntimeException' 
with message 'Session validation failed' in \zendframework\library\Zend\Session\SessionManager.php on line 111.
```

Is there a callback or something else that I'm not doing to prevent the code from just dying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is php we don't use callbacks, but throw exceptions. You need to catch the exception and handle it from there on out.

I would recommend using the event manager and listening on the dispatch event to validate the user.

Comment: That must be a comment, not an answer.